# Windows 10 photos not opening after selecting default

Tags: windows-10, photos, regedit, default-settings

I have a user who when trying to open jpgs, or other photos double clicks on the photos and gets the "How do you want to open this file"

If they click on the Photos app or any other application the "How do you want to open this file" will just pop up again and not actually open the photo or run any app.

If they right click on the photo and Open With -> and select paint or another application it will open with that application.

I've messed with default applications for jpgs, I've reinstalled the Photo application (that ships with Windows 10), I've also tried adding 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open] commands that I found here https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/8550-unable-replace-photos-app-photo-viewer-default-10240-a-2.html.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any thoughts on fixes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings and click on Apps. On the left click on Default apps.

Scroll down and click on Choose default apps by file type.

Set Photos as default app for .jpeg and .jpg file formats (and other file formats that you want to open in Photos).

Comment: Yeah, I've checked those settings and they say to open with the Photos app. It still asks for a default program when trying to open even though a default is set. It's almost like after clicking what program to open with it doesn't tell the application to open.